# trying to get .csh history via arrow keys

Tags: linux, unix, shell, command-history

I was wondering if there was a easy way to get the up and down arrows to scroll command history while in .csh?I know that it is done like that in bash and sort of use to being able to work that way

Answer (score 1):

The [tcsh shell](http://www.tcsh.org) is backwards compatible with `csh` and has support for history browsing using up/down arrow keys. It's readily available on most systems that support `csh`.